# Type Mismatch error while copy data from excel to another excel

Tags: excel, vba

Type Mismatch error while copy data from excel to another excel

I am getting Type Mismatch error .. please help thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim dataRange As String
Dim myData As Workbook

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
dataRange = Range("A1:T1")

Set myData = Workbook.Open("C:\Users\mahather\Desktop\Report\Test.xlsx")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:T3").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:T3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:T3")
RowCount = dataRange
End With
myData.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile - `Set myData = Workbook.Open...` should be `Set myData = Workbooks.Open...` Also, `RowCount` isn't declared anywhere in the code given (although it could be declared elsewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will run and I've tried to guess your purpose. You will be left with an open workbook.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim dataRange As variant, myData As Workbook

    dataRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1:T1").value

    Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mahather\Desktop\Report\Test.xlsx")

    with mydata.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        with .Range("A3:T3").CurrentRegion
            .offset(.rows.count, 0).resize(1, .columns.count) = dataRange
        end with
        .parent.save
        '.parent.close savechanges:=true
    end with
End Sub
```

Comment: its showing Object Required error on 4th line which is Set myData = Workbook.Open("C:\Users\mahather\Desktop\Report\Test.xlsx")
 can you double check code please @Jeeped

Comment: It should be Workbook**s**.open not Workbook.open. btw, that was your code and one part that I could not check without creating a test workbook and a directory structure to match your own.

Comment: its working but not all the lines copied.. Only A1 cell copied @Jeeped

Comment: Yes, that is what your original code tried to do. I don't like playing 20 questions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with:

```
RowCount = dataRange
```

because `RowCount` is a *Long* or *Integer* and `DataRange` is a multi-cell *Range*